# Cave sounds on Bedrock Edition

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I can't seem to get the `/playsound` command to play ANY cave sounds nor underwater sounds. I can't find the right syntax for Bedrock, only Java. Does anybody know a command that works for cave sounds on Bedrock?

Answer (score 2):

[You can find a list of values on the wiki.](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sounds.json/Bedrock_Edition_values)

Unfortunately, you can't play cave sounds in Bedrock Edition, only Java.

Answer (score 2):

I think they’re going to add cave ambience to Bedrock in the Caves and Cliffs update because you can do the cave ambience play sound command in Beta.

Answer (score 0):

In beta 1.16.0.57 cave ambience was added in bedrock, but it plays too frequently and mojang or the community wanted to fix it on beta 1.16.0.59

On beta 1.16.0.59 the ambience will play less frequently

According to an animoapp user

Cave sounds can occur in every area that is at least 3x3x3 blocks but they tend to be heard much more often in bigger areas

Answer (score 0):

```
/playsound ambient.cave @p
```

or

```
/playsound ambience.cave @p
```

(I forget which one)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/292138)

Comment: @KyleRone This question is asking for a command that does something, and this answer provides a (poorly formatted) command. I don't see how you can say it should be a comment.

Comment: @pppery I did not feel it was composed enough to be an objective answer. Saying its this or this doesnt really seem to me that its a thought out answer. Thats why I felt it probably should be a comment.